# Save webpage concluded instead HTML only

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge

I'm currently using a VBA code in a spreadsheet to download a webpage, the issue is that this is downloading only the html page, without the folder that is downloaded when we go to the browser and select "Save As".

Below I'm showing the explanation with images - I would like to know if is possible to, directly from VBA, download the concluded page (with folder that comes with images, etc.) instead only the HTML.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
    Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub datafeed()

src = "https://google.com"
dlpath = "C:\Users\User\Downloads\Test\"
URLDownloadToFile 0, src, dlpath & "test.html", 0, 0

End Sub
```

**How is currently downloading:**

[image: How is currently downloading]

**How I would like to download (like when I select Save As in the browser):**
[image: How should download]

[image: Inside folder of complete download]

Does someone know how to configure VBA to download the webpage and the folder with the files instead only the webpage?

Comment: As far as  I know, you cannot download a folder directly in the browser, if you need, you can compress it into a browser downloadable format, such as zip format. Simply refer to this document to learn more about [Common MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types).

Comment: Can you give us a reproducible example? Is there a webpage you are considering?

Comment: Hey QHarr, https://google.com can be used as the example. I don't share the final website because this works only on internal network.